# Why C program bug is disappearing when executed with Valgrind?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, heap-memory, valgrind

I'm malloc-ing two pretty big structures at the command-function start: first is a plain structure of arrays and single values, second have its inner sub-structures.

After that, I'm filling first structure with some filling_functions(struct_1), and then I fill struct_2 with other, using data from first struct and from external files.
What is filled from struct_1 - can be minded as keys-data and "render" of key-data.
What is filled from files - is value-data, target information to collect as a result; all value-data are extracted by keys-data fields.

Finally, I'm outputting all values from struct_2.

Scheme of my code some kind of that:

```
typedef struct struct_1
{
  // a lot of arrays, ints, chars..
} 
STRUCT_1;


typedef struct sub_struct_A
{
  char strings[5][100];
  // arrays, ints, chars..
} 
SUB_A;

typedef struct sub_struct_B
{
  char strings[5][10][10];
  // arrays, ints, chars..
} 
SUB_B;

typedef struct struct_2
{
  SUB_A sub_struct_A[10];
  SUB_B sub_struct_B[100];
} 
STRUCT_2;


main()
{
    // take it as somewhere before a config struct was initialized..
    char input[100]={0};
    // no matter whats inside..
    some_input(input, config);

    STRUCT_1 *s1 = NULL;  
    s1 = (s1 *)malloc(sizeof(STRUCT_1));

    STRUCT_2 *s2 = NULL;  
    s2 = (s2 *)malloc(sizeof(STRUCT_2));
    
    fill_struct_1(input, s1, config);
    fill_struct_2(s1, s2, config);

    output_struct_2(s2, config);

    free(s1); free(s2);
}


void fill_struct_2(STRUCT_1 *s1, STRUCT_2 *s2, CONF_STRUCT config)
{
    fill_keys_data(s1, s2); 
    fill_value_data(s1, s2, config);
}

void fill_value_data(STRUCT_1 *s1, STRUCT_2 *s2, CONF_STRUCT config)
{
    get__tokenized_buffer__from_file();

    extract_values__from_buf_and_s1__by_conf(s1, s2, config);

}
```

The problem is:
When I'm outputting sequentially all entries from arrays of both sub-structs, on the `sub-struct_B[0].strings[0][1]` -- I get the piece of data from `sub-struct_A[0].strings[0]`.
And for `sub-struct_B[0].some_int_val_X` -- I get value `(757935400)`, which is not allowed for that field, possible maximum for which is about `(150)`.

All other output is always OK. Each `(i)` in `'sub-struct_B[i]'` is filled and outputted OK.

When I'm using Valgrind to check, what's the trace of my problem, the problem just disappears..
And yes, Valgrind says that there's `possibly lost: 8,904 bytes in 8 blocks`.

But I'm very new to this tool, so that information gives me just nothing. Now I don't know how to fix these possible leaks; my code - works, not absolutely, but fine. Maybe my problem lies upon this Valgrind message, i don't know.

Filling logic of each sub-struct is huge, with `rand()`'s and inner filtrations and extractors. I can't give an abstract scheme of this logic, sorry.

Now I'm guessing, maybe something goes wrong with some distant side pointers. But I can't imagine where to start my search. All 99 entries from `sub-struct_B` are outputted correctly, but only [0]-entry gives me bad output.

Rarely, [0]-entry even gives me not that data from `sub_struct_A`, but a lot of garbage from other places.

My only guess is that I am doing wrong pointer arithmetics somewhere. Not so big idea..

Can anybody give me some hints to start?

I know that I'm one-on-one with my problem, just seeking for good suggestions from people being experienced specially in C-pointers debugging.

*If this guess-game is not what you guys seeking on, than give me an answer on one simple question, please:*

**How can that be, that with Valgrind -- there is 100% correct output, and without - corrupted? How Valgrind can fix the program without fixing the code??**

Only difference between execs, is that for Valgrind I am compiling with flag '-g', but for common use - with '-o'.

Thanks.

Comment: `sizeof(s1)` is the size of the *pointer* variable `s1`, not what it might point to. You probably want `sizeof *s1` instead.

Comment: You probbaly should learn another very valuable tool. It's called debugger and it exists in virtually every decent environnment.

Comment: you have a buffer overflow or you use de-allocated/uninitialized memory somewhere.  Valgrind to identify memory issues will put gaps/guards in between memory allocations and other things specifically to detect memory issues. And it's report confirms this.

Comment: We cannot effectively debug a *description* of your code or an *approximation to* your code.  The details matter.  Since we also cannot debug your *whole* code in most cases, our expectation is that you reduce the problem to a [mre] and present that.  As it turns out, producing an MRE is a pretty effective debugging technique in its own right, so you should consider the effort -- both of doing it and of learning to do it well -- as time well spent.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, yeah, there are a lot of good things to learn. Thank you, that did not help at all to understand the situation.

Comment: @Rob, that clarifies something, thanks!

Comment: @MkKvease The best part is having gone thru this, you will never forget it ;) We all learned the hard way even if some forgot what it was like back then. LOL